# bootstrap validator makes the form submit to fire on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I am trying to submit a form on click on the submit button which is prevented from it's default action and tries to check a condition first.

This is my code:

```
$('#payment-form').bootstrapValidator({
        live: 'disabled',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            cardNumber: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: $('#cardNumber').attr('data-error-required')
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

    $('#paymentSubmit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $('#payment-form');

        if(basket.length >= 1 || basketTotalPrice > 0){    
            $form.bootstrapValidator('validate');
            if ($form.bootstrapValidator('isValid')) {
                $form.submit();
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('basket empty');
        }
    })
```

The form is being validated on the first click and does not submit, and the submit fires on the second click!

Comment: the event gets listened twice? on which line does it break, you able to get till there?

Comment: There are no breaks in this code. everything is fine except that the form does not submit on the first click after being validated

Comment: can you create a fiddle to check this? since if you are saying the form does not submit there can be multiple reasons for the same. cannot tell what `$form.bootstrapValidator('validate')` will do without looking at the form's html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your issue:

```
 if(basket.length >= 1 || basketTotalPrice > 0){    
        $form.bootstrapValidator('validate');
        if ($form.bootstrapValidator('isValid')) {
            $form.submit();
        }
    }
```

What seems to be happening is that this line

```
 $form.bootstrapValidator('validate');
```

is doing its job and running the validation, but the validation does not complete before it jumps to this line:

```
if ($form.bootstrapValidator('isValid')) {
```

And that is where its issue starts. It does not pass your second conditional because it has not finished setting its valid condition yet. Then, after it fails, the check validation completes and sets your conditional to valid. The second time you click, the validation already happened so the form submits.

To fix, you need to hold your second conditional until you are sure that the validation has completed first. A callback from the validator would be perfect for this.

Comment: This is not an answer. You could post it as a comment